# Discord-xp Rank card .setRank

Tags: canvas, discord, discord.js

Hi I've been trying to make a Discord.Js XP bot with Discord-xp and im trying to make a rank command but i cant make it show what rank the actual user is it always says Rank : 1

```
if(command === "rank") {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || bot.users.cache.get(args[0])|| message.author
        if (!target) {
        target = message.author;
        }        
        const user = await Levels.fetch(target.id, message.guild.id);
        const neededXp = Levels.xpFor(parseInt(user.level) + 1);
        
        if(!user) return message.channel.send('Keep talking you dont have any xp')
        let color = message.member.displayHexColor;
        if (color == '#000000') color = message.member.hoistRole.hexColor;
        const rank = new canvacord.Rank()
        .setAvatar(target.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true, format: 'gif'}))
        .setCurrentXP(user.xp)
        .setLevel(user.level)
        .setRank(user.rank)
        .setRequiredXP(neededXp)
        .setStatus(target.presence.status)
        .setProgressBar(color, "COLOR")
        .setUsername(target.username)
        .setDiscriminator(target.discriminator)
        rank.build()
        .then(data =>{
            const rankcard = new Discord.MessageAttachment(data, 'rankcard.gif')
            message.channel.send(rankcard)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord-xp has no rank property, You just have to replace `const user = await Levels.fetch(target.id, message.guild.id);` with`const user = await Levels.fetch(target.id, message.guild.id, true);` (That fetchs the position) and use `user.position` instead of `user.rank`.